# android Lollipop notification white empty circle

Tags: android, notifications

I done this

> ```
>               Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
>                             getApplicationContext());
>                     RemoteViews mContentView = new RemoteViews(
>                             getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
>                             R.layout.custom_notification);
>                     Uri alertSound = RingtoneManager
>                             .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
>                     notificationBuilder.setSound(alertSound);
>                     mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, getResources()
>                             .getString(R.string.activation_code)
>                             + ": "
>                             + mUUID);
>                     notificationBuilder.setContent(mContentView);
>                     notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(getResources()
>                             .getString(R.string.activation_code));
>                     notificationBuilder
>                             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
>                     notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
>                     NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
>                     manager.notify(11151990,
>                             notificationBuilder.getNotification());
> ```

Very simple, this works perfectly until today i got my lollipop os for nexus 7. the notification icon on top is showing white circle.How can I fix that?
When I drag from top, the notification looks normal inside it.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

On that page, you can see under "Don't", your notification icons should be only two colors: white on transparent background. The icon in the pulled-down notification is a different one, with less restrictions.